# Inviting a user to chat from the profile page?

Tags: support, chat, faq-update-request

In the [chat faq](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#notifications) under "*How do I know when someone is talking?*" section it says:

> If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar.

However, so far I never saw any "invite to chat" link in user profile. Wrong faq statement, or are my eyes going bad?

Also worth to mention another slight mistake - user card pops up when I hover the avatar, clicking it will take me to the profile page.

Comment: this feature does not seem to be documented in the chat FAQ. also note you have to have _entered_ into any chat rooms you want to invite users to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Point one:

[image: inviting functionality in chat profile]

The dropdown should contain the same possible invite rooms you see in the user popup for that particular user (i.e. all rooms you can invite the user to). It will not appear if there's no room to invite to (which usually means the other user already is in all rooms you are in).

Point two:

> user card pops up when I hover the avatar, clicking it will take me to the profile page.

Uhm, no? If that actually happens like that, you have found a bug, but this sounds like such an improbable thing to happen that I rather think there's a misunderstanding here. Can you clarify where precisely you're hovering, clicking, etc.?

Comment: I feel so stupid - I'm so used to profile and user card being terms only here that I didn't figure it means the **chat** profile and **chat room** user card. Thanks! Well, if it happened to me guess it might happen to others, so this answer of yours have chance to be useful for others as well and I'm happy for that. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. I suppose I can change the chat FAQ to say "user's chat profile page".

Comment: Yes this would be great, and also "*from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar in the chat room*" will clarify it once and for all. :)

Comment: Fair enough; updated.

Comment: Wow thanks for the ubber fast response!!

Answer (score -1):

The original quote:

> If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar.

Now: as far as I can tell, it's **no longer possible** to invite a user from their *profile*.

Instead (with added emphasis):

> … from the user's *chat* profile page …

Related:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications
- [Invite someone into chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146569/166799) (2012-09-10 – 2014-04-24) and various other questions.

Comment: Sorry but this really does not fit as answer. SE developer already gave full and official answer, there's essentially nothing more to add.

Comment: I could have made a comment, but it's not as easy to format – to make things clear – in a comment. The apparent loss of functionality is a point of reference from http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276204/166799

Comment: My point is, this answer is meaningless. You say " it's no longer possible to invite a user from their profile" but it was never possible, that's the whole point of this question - and balpha explained this, and changed the text in the faq so that it won't be confusing anymore.

Comment: OK, now I see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/inviting-a-user-to-chat-from-the-profile-page/276203#comment341214_126103 in the commentary beneath the answer.