# How to start a chat about an answer?

Tags: support, comments, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to import comments into a chat room without the link appearing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing)
>   [Create comment-spawned chatrooms for the post, not for the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-post-not-for-the-users)

When there are too many comments, SO suggests to start a chat. But is there an easy way to start a chat about an answer before SO "thinks" there are too many comments? I can't see a link/button to do this...

Comment: Add lots of comments, then when the chat suggestion pops up, delete them?

Comment: [Less facetiously, there is an easy (er, maybe) way to do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/inviting-a-user-to-chat-from-the-profile-page)

Comment: @Won't ha, thanks for the suggestions ;)

Comment: @Won't that's for a profile page - this one is for an answer?

Comment: @naxa You're right. No way you can find the profile of a user from an answer.  No possible way.  I take my suggestion back.  I also can fly.