# No invite option in chat

Tags: support, chat

I have encountered this situation frequently where I don't find any option to invite a user to any room on chat.stackoverflow.com

Why and how this happens?

Normally we get option to invite user as:

> [image]

But in some case, I am not getting:

> [image]

How can I invite such users?

Comment: Reading [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/inviting-a-user-to-chat-from-the-profile-page?rq=1) and its answer there is this line *It will not appear if there's no room to invite to (which usually means the other user already is in all rooms you are in).* Can that be the case?

Comment: NO this is not the case..

Comment: @Tamanna what make you think this way? You sure there are rooms that you're in and the user where you don't see "Invite this user" is not?

Comment: Then balpha has to answer this question explaining what the unusual conditions are when you can't invite a user...

Comment: How can i invite the user who never been to the other ROOM where i want to call(invite) him??

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you are in the room which is gallery **and** the other user (whom you want to invite) has no access for that gallery mode room.

If you go to other public room, and then refresh the user's profile, you will find an option for invite to for only public room.

Edit:

I was in 2 private rooms and 1 public room. When I click on your profile, I got an option to invite you to either public room, or gallery for which you have access.

[image]

[image]

Comment: no, for public room also, I am not getting option to invite

Comment: I tested before answering. Refresh the page after entering public room in which other user is not. @Tamanna Checked with your profile for Smart devs lab (gallery), in which I got option of invite, jQuery mobile (public) in which got option for invite, and other gallery room (for which you don't have access), for which I didn't get option.